# Javascript not recognizing jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have my HTML load two scripts....

```
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

In my script.js I am calling a simple jQuery function .show() and .hide() wrapped inside a function

```
function visible() {
alert('Hi');
document.getElementById('login-error').show();
document.getElementById('login-error').hide(6000);
}
```

I am running the function from a php echo

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>visible();</script>";
```

But it doesn't matter where I execute the function from, it doesn't recognize the jQuery functions. The alert goes off but I cannot get it to recognize the jQuery script.

I run firebug in firefox and it tells me .show() and .hide() are not recognized as functions.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You cant mix pure JavaScript and jquery like that. Keep it consistent

Comment: You aren't using any jQuery functions. You've made up new functions that don't exist and tried to execute them.

Comment: The show and hide functions operate on the jQuery object.

Comment: You are correct dear sir, it does all things and you should surely have jqury in your enviroment production many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods `show` and `hide` execute over a `jQuery` object but you're trying to execute it on a `Element` instance. It just doesn't have those methods. You're mixing up jQuery (`show` and `hide`) and "plain" javascript (`document.getElementById`). You should do

```
$('#login-error').show();
$('#login-error').hide(6000);
```

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById` does not return a jQuery collection, and jQuery does not add it's functions to the prototype of the DOM nodes. This code would be written as the following in jQuery.

```
function visible() {
    alert('Hi');
    $('#login-error').show();
    $('#login-error').hide(6000);
}
```